# Estimating skewness of histogram in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics

What test can I do in MATLAB to test the spread of a histogram? For example, in the given set of histograms, I am only interested in 1,2,3,5 and 7 (going from left to right, top to bottom) because they are less spread out. How can I obtain a value that will tell me if a histogram is positively skewed?

It may be possible using Chi-Squared tests but I am not sure what the MATLAB code will be for that.
[image]

Comment: One could argue that histogram #6 is also skewed as a good number of entries are binned at bin 0, while the rest of the bins are thinly spread out.  I think #6 should be included in your criteria as well, but that's just me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [standard definition of skewness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Sample_skewness).  In other words, you can use:

[image]

You compute the mean of your data and you use the above equation to calculate skewness.  Positive and negative skewness are like so:

[image]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness)</sup>

As such, the larger the value, the more positively skewed it is.  The more negative the value, the more negatively skewed it is.

---

Now to compute the mean of your histogram data, it's quite simple.  You simply do a weighted sum of the histogram entries and divide by the total number of entries.  Given that your histogram is stored in `h`, the bin centres of your histogram are stored in `x`, you would do the following.  What I will do here is assume that you have bins from 0 up to `N-1` where `N` is the total number of bins in the histogram... judging from your picture:

```
x = 0:numel(h)-1; %// Judging from your pictures
num_entries = sum(h(:));
mu = sum(h.*x) / num_entries;
skew = ((1/num_entries)*(sum((h.*x - mu).^3))) / ...
       ((1/(num_entries-1))*(sum((h.*x - mu).^2)))^(3/2);
```

`skew` would contain the numerical measure of skewness for a histogram that follows that formula.  Therefore, with your problem statement, you will want to look for skewness numbers that are positive and large.  I can't really comment on what threshold you should look at, but look for positive numbers that are much larger than most of the histograms that you have.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What I asked I think has been answered. But from the results, it seems like skew of number 3 is 304 whereas number 4 is 750... What I think will be helpful to me is, if I can check if the first 90% of the values are found in range 1-50...

Comment: @NeilDA - I made a tiny mistake with my formula, so you may want to check my post and use the updated code.  I forgot a couple of brackets.

Comment: @NeilDA - If you desire that, then perform `cumsum` on the histogram, and check to see if the 50th entry is 90% of the total entries accumulated... so something like: `c = cumsum(h); check = c(50) > 0.9*sum(h(:));` `check` will contain `true` or `false` which determines whether at least 90% of the histogram entries are within the first 50 bins.

Comment: I did it using a for loop but cumsum way is definitely better! ;)